# How to change a document's _type in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following models inside a Rails application:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
end

class Admin < User
  ...
end
```

I get a user:

```
u = User.find(some_key)
```

And try to change the _type:

```
u._type  # => "User"
u._type = "Admin"
u.save
u._type  # => "Admin"
```

But if I reload the object it's still a user:

```
u.reload
u._type = "User"
```

What is the *correct* way to change this?

Comment: Its working fine for me(with type column). Try with 'type' field instead of '_type'

Comment: @Ashish Doesn't work here: u.type #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for #<User:0x00000104eaf510>

Comment: Try u.write_attribute('_type', 'Admin'). And besides, perhaps your save failed (validation, etc). Try save!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ended up solving it by using a raw MongoDB query:

```
users.update( { :"_id" => user.id }, { :"$set" => { :"_type" => "Admin" }})
```

Comment: How to run a raw query with mongoid? :)

Answer (score 8):

you could also use [Model#update_attribute](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#update_attribute) to stay with mongoid:

```rb
user.update_attribute(:_type, "Admin")
```