# Instantiate mongoid subclasses by _type field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

From the Mongoid docs I see that if I have the following:

```
class Base
  include Mongoid::Document
end
class InheritedA < Base
end
class InheritedB < Base
end
```

I can do the following, which will get stored with the "_type" attribute.

```
a = InheritedA.new
a.save
```

Mongoid will create the following document.

```
{ _type: "InheritedA" }
```

My problem is that later on I have a function which has only the String _type value and I wish to instantiate the proper type. I have tried this:

```
Base.new({ _type: mytype });
```

However, Mongoid thinks this is a dynamic attribute and rejects it. I know turning on dynamic attributes is not the proper course because I don't want to allow that behavior in the general case.

I want to avoid having to do something like this:

```
ob = nil
if mytype == "InheritedA"
  ob = InheritedA.new
elsif
    ...
```

Does anyone know the proper method for accomplishing this?

Comment: I think this works as designed. If you want to build a type of `InheritedA` then you are supposed to call `InheritedA.new`. But, this person solved it by calling a raw MongoDB update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306646/how-to-change-a-documents-type-in-mongoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can tackle this. First one creates a base class document and then converts it into a subclass document. Using this method you would only be able to initialize based on fields defined in base class:

```
# attributes = {base_key1: value1, base_key2: value2}
Base.new(attributes).becomes(mytype.constantize)
```

Second one creates a document of subclass directly and you can initialize any fields for subclass:

```
# attributes = {base_key1: value1, base_key2: value2, sub_key3: value3}
Mongoid::Factory.build(mytype.constantize, attributes)
```

Comment: This still relies on me having the actual class and not just a String _type value, doesn't it?

Comment: I assumed you had the string in `mytype`. `[constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/String/constantize)` converts a string to corresponding class.

Comment: +1 for `#constantize`. `{ _type: "InheritedA" }[:_type].constantize.new` is the same as `InheritedA.new`.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the Mongoid source I came to realize that Mongoid does indeed try to instantiate the proper type based on looking at the _type field when one does something like this:

```
Base.new({ _type: "InheritedA" })
```

It does so by looking at the base class' descendants. Apparently my ruby classes are being lazy loaded, and by default the Base.descendants call returns an empty list! I'm not sure if this is due to using JRuby, or a quirk about Rails development mode, or the config.cache_classes value, or something else, but I was able to solve it by doing this:

```
class Base
  Descendant1.inspect
  Descendant2.inspect
  ...
```

Yes, it's a real pain, but it allows you to work with Rails reloading your classes.

Comment: Initializing the document using Base.new like above will always create `Base` class document. It will not respond to methods specific to base classes. If you check the class of newly created document it would be `Base` and not `InheritedA`.